# Isothermal Atmosphere

Tags: ideal-gas

I was taught that for isothermal atmosphere:

$\frac{dP}{dz}=-\rho g$

How come the equation is only true for isothermal atmosphere? I suppose $dP$ can be caused by changed in temperature as well?

Comment: The density would change with the temperature in addition to the pressure, so one would have to know the temperature profile.

Answer (score 2):

> How come the equation is only true for isothermal atmosphere?

Whoever taught you that that equation is valid for an isothermal atmosphere and only for an isothermal atmosphere was just wrong.

The equation in question is for a fluid in hydrostatic equilibrium. Imagine a small cylindrical plug of fluid, oriented vertically. That little cylinder has two forces that act it, the downward gravitational force due to the mass of the fluid in the cylinder, and the pressure on the top, bottom, and sides of the plug. Horizontal movement results if the pressure on one side is greater than the pressure on the opposite side. Vertical movement results if the force due to the pressure differential between bottom and top doesn't exactly balance out the downward gravitational force. With [only a tiny bit of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium#Mathematical_consideration), the condition that results in that balance is
$$\frac{dP}{dz}=−\rho g$$
where $z$ is the radial distance from the center (or height above some reference), $P$ is pressure, $\rho$ is the local density, and $g$ is the local acceleration due to gravitation.

One way to look at this expression is that it represents a stability condition. It says that a cylindrical plug of fluid will fall / stay in place /rise if the pressure gradient is less than / equal to / greater than the gradient specified by the hydrostatic equilibrium condition.
 There is nothing in that expression that restricts its use to an isothermal atmosphere. This expression applies to the Earth's atmosphere, the interior of our Sun, and even the interior of the Earth. The first two are anything but isothermal, and the latter obviously isn't even a gas.

Suppose the fluid in question is an ideal gas. The way in which temperature varies with altitude combined with the hydrostatic equilibrium condition and the ideal gas law ($P = \rho R^\ast T$, where $P$ is pressure, $\rho$ is density, $T$ is temperature, and $R^\ast$ is the gas constant for the gas in question) specifies how pressure and density must vary in order for the gas to be in hydrostatic equilibrium.

Assuming $g$ and $T$ are constant, this results in an exponential drop in pressure with increased altitude:
$$\frac{P(z)}{P_0} = \exp\left(-\frac{g}{R^\ast T} (z-z_0)\right)$$
where $z_0$ is a reference altitude and $P_0$ is the pressure at that altitude. Density follows a similar exponential drop with altitude.

With if temperature isn't constant? Suppose temperature changes linearly with altitude: $T(z) = T_0 + \alpha (z-z_0)$. Instead of an exponential drop, this results in a power law drop in pressure with increased altitude:
$$\frac{P(z)}{P_0} = \left(\frac {T(z)} {T_0}\right)^{-g / (\alpha R^\ast)}$$
A constant temperature and a temperature that varies linearly with altitude both result in nice closed form expressions. Many of the older models of the Earth's atmosphere split the atmosphere into regions where the temperature is either constant or varies linearly with altitude precisely because of this. More modern versions numerically integrate the relevant equations.

Comment: I don't understand this answer really.  You seem to understand the reason why that statement was made; but dance around it.  Those systems aren't technically perfectly described by hydrostatics, but without thermal variation there would should be no convective effects, leading to _no_ net vertical motions.

Comment: @JMac - The body of the question asks *How come the equation is only true for isothermal atmosphere?* That is incorrect. $\frac{dP}{dz} = -\rho g$ is true for any body in hydrostatic equilibrium. Another way to look at it is that this is the necessary and sufficient condition for a body to be in hydrostatic equilibrium. Temperature does not directly come into play.

Comment: But a body with a thermal gradient will not be in hydrostatic equilibrium.  It may be in _approximately_ hydrostatic equilibrium, but you could also argue that's because it's fairly isothermal.  The point is that if there is a thermal gradient vertically, this will be violated in some form, albeit perhaps not a practical amount.  Consider that the equation also doesn't quite apply if $\rho (h)$.

Comment: @JMac -- What makes you say that? A body with a non-zero temperature gradient most certainly can be in hydrostatic equilibrium. For example, for an ideal gas with temperature that changes linearly with altitude, $T(h) = T_0 + ah$, the hydrostatic equilibrium condition is that $\frac{P}{P_0} = \left(\frac T {T_0}\right)^\frac{-g}{aR^\ast}$ where $R^\ast$ is the gas constant for that gas.